# Font awesome icons looked ok in staging then started aligning to the top once live

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I use font awesome icons and everything was aligned in the middle as it should in staging. Once the site went live, all the font awesome icons moved up to the top and I can't figure out why. I compared the css being used on chrome developer tools but so far I can't see any difference.

Here's the link to the homepage. http://studyusa.com/en/ You can see that the magnifying glass on the top navigation, all of the social network buttons under the slider, and menu icons next to "Browse Schools by Degree Level" all moved up.

Hope I can get any hints.

-- update

Wow, thanks for all the answers! However I must apologize to everybody because I checked the site today and it looks the way it should without me changing any code. Now I'm curious as to why something like this is possible.

Comment: Also, please don't say add padding. It looked fine without adding padding while in staging.

Comment: You compared all the css or from live to staging or just the relevant bit?

Answer (score 2):

iam not sure about this, hope this is because of various line-heights used.. but try update the class ".fa" below. Hope this will fix your issue..

```
.fa {
    line-height: inherit!important;
}
```

Comment: The .fa element is indeed missing any (line-)height. Inheriting it from its parent element is also what I would recommend. Though it works without the !important too. !important should not be used unless it is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this:

```
.fa {
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    top: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't alter `.fa` CSS, this is needed for every icon and will break every other icon you have!

Instead, add this to your css:

```
.search-trigger {padding:15px;}
```

I tested that in Chrome and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.toggle-make a {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

I have played with Chrome Inspector and it seems that floating has something to do with it. As far as I can see, you are using `display: block;` with width but no height.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this code

```
.fa-twitter:before{
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
}
```